# Getting exception while calling procedure through JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I am working on an application that requires getting data from the stored procedures written in Oracle db. I am using `JdbcTemplate` of `Spring` to call the procedure. But calling the procedure results the following exception

Stack trace :-

```
> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
> CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call
> V2_tl.PKG_TECH_LINKING.p_get_model_list_intl_ctry(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}];
> nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table
> or view does not exist
```

Please tell me the solution

Comment: What's unclear about "*ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*"

Comment: I am able to run that procedure in Oracle, but when calling from code, getting this exception. Statement is quiet clear as it suggest that table i am trying to access does not exist, but it is present.What's the problem

Comment: Sounds as if you are using different users.

Comment: Is it related to the access permissions ? U saying this way ?

Comment: if you are trying to call a stored procedure take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9361835/3686755) answer

Comment: I am using CallableStatementCreator for the invocation

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same user in you code that the one you use when you run the procedure in Oracle itself? And are you accessing the table as the same user that owns the table or is it another user that needs the right permissions set?

Comment: Solved ! it was due to the different user being used while calling from code. Just granted the user permission for the tables involved.