# DAO factory pattern createConnection from datasource

Tags: java, spring

Referring to this article on DAO factory pattern, 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

I have a `CloudscapeDAOFactory` , that has a  `public static Connection createConnection()` method.
I am using `DriverManager.registerDriver()` and `DriverManager.getConnection()` to create connection.

```
//DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
//conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
```

The individual DAO classes like say `CloudscapeCustomerDAO` [Example 9.4] calls  `CloudscapeDAOFactory.createConnection()` to get a connection as required.

```
public class CloudscapeCustomerDAO implements 
    CustomerDAO {

  public CloudscapeCustomerDAO() {
    // initialization 
  }

  // The methods in the class can use
  // CloudscapeDAOFactory.createConnection() 
  // to get a connection as required
```

**Question:** Now I am implementing connection pooling, and my **problem** is retaining the '`static`' keyword in the 
`createConnection()` of the `CloudscapeDAOFactory`.

**CloudscapeDAOFactory.java**

```
private DataSource dataSource;
private static Connection conn = null;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


public static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {
  conn = dataSource.getConnection()// incorrect static reference// compile time error
  // If I remove 'static' then CloudscapeCustomerDAO need an instance of CloudscapeDAOFactory to call this method!
  // If I plan to retain the 'static' then I need to declare DataSource also as static, which I feel is incorrect.

}
```

**Springconfig.xml**

```
<bean id="springDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" >
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SPRING_UNNI" />
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="username" value="unni" />
  <property name="password" value="unni" />
  <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" />
  <property name="initialSize" value="20" />
  <property name="maxActive" value="30" />
</bean>

<bean id="cloudscapeDAOFactory" class="com.myapp.dao.CloudscapeDAOFactory">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="springDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

update: `JDBCTemplate` can be used to call Stored Procedures too. Reference: [Spring JDBC Template for calling Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361538/spring-jdbc-template-for-calling-stored-procedures)
This question is not w.r.to using `JDBCTemplate`. Its just a core java question on effectively using the createConnection() of a factory

update2: Irrelevant to this thread, but placing a note:

note: Got an issue while attempting for connection:
error: `TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor`

fixed by changing

```
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SPRING_UNNI" />
```

to

```
 <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/SPRING_UNNI" />
```

Comment: Just inject the datasource and get a connection or even better use a `JdbcTemplate` don't start messing aruond yourself with factories.

Comment: My application has this factory design pattern in place, hence I am looking for a way to resolve it in the same approach. I understand, injecting the datasource directly in the individual DAO's, which I don't prefer as per design. Also, I am not using `JDBC Template` because I am calling the Stored Procedures from my code

Comment: I'll look at JDBC Template, I can use it to call SPs, but any way to resolve this w/o going to that

Comment: Don't tie things together with static methods simple as that. Also the reason to not use `JdbcTemplate` doesn't make any sense you can call procedures with it just as that.

Comment: Yes, I took back that reason for not using the `JdbcTemplate`. I updated my comment. Ok, so your suggestion would be not declaring the `createConnection` method as `static` and let the individual DAO's call the `createConnection` method thru the instance of the `CloudscapeDAOFactory` , Is that understanding correct?  from a core java perspective

Comment: I would inject the `DataSource` in each dao. Calling `createConnection` on the `CloudscapeDAOFactory` or `getConnection` on a `DataSource` is basically the same. However I strongly suggest you take a better look into spring especially regarding JDBC access and resource management (i.e. connection).

Comment: I agree with the first statement, thanks,  For the reference, will this do? http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html . And Can you please post as an answer so that I can close it

Comment: That is a good start.