# How to call a stored procedure from a Spring Batch Tasklet?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

It is mentioned that a TaskletStep in Spring Batch can be used to call a stored procedure. Could anyone provide an example of how to invoke a Stored Procedure from a TaskletStep? So far I have done this but it throws an exception saying "*Configuration problem: The element [callStoredProcedure] is unreachable"*

```
       <job id="job1">
          <step id="step1">
                <tasklet ref="myTasklet"/>
          </step>
       </job>

       <bean id="myTasklet" class="MyClass">
             <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
             <property name="sql" value="call stored_procedure()"/>
       </bean>
```

Java Class

```
        class MyClass implements Tasklet{
               @Override
               public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
        ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                  JdbcTemplate myJDBC=new JdbcTemplate(getDataSource());
                  myJDBC.execute(sql);
                  return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
             }      
        }
```

How and where should the stored procedure be configured? Would be grateful to receive any pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JDBC Template for calling Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361538/spring-jdbc-template-for-calling-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
value="call stored_procedure()"
```

just put

```
value="stored_procedure"
```

without () on end. That should resolve your issue