# Calling stored function using call in Spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pk_sahil AS  
      procedure squareNumDummy(x in number,y in number) is
      begin
        dbms_output.put_line(x*y);
        insert into sahil values('package',111);
      end squareNumDummy;
      function sumFun( x in number , y in number ) return number is
      begin
        insert into sahil values('function',222);
        return x+y;
      end sumFun;
    END pk_sahil; 
    /
    create or replace package pk_sahil as
      procedure squareNumDummy(x in number, y in number);
      function sumFun(x in number, y in number ) return number;
    end pk_sahil;
    /
```

I've made this package with a function and a procedure in it and i'm trying to call them from my java code using spring jdbctemplate. But procedure is running fine but unable to call this function.

```
int param1 =5 , param2 = 10;
jdbcTemplate.update( "call pk_sahil.squareNumDummy(?,?)",param1,param2);
```

this procedure is running fine.

```
jdbcTemplate.update( "call pk_sahil.sumFun(?,?)",param1,param2);
```

upon running this function i'm getting below error

[console log of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ1fC.jpg)

Please correct me whether i'm not calling that function right way or i need to handle the return variable from function? How can i call that function from jdbctemplate.update(' call... ') method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JDBC Template for calling Stored Procedures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361538/spring-jdbc-template-for-calling-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a stored function from `jdbcTemplate.queryForObject()` as follows:

```
int sum = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT pk_sahil.squareNumDummy(?,?)", new Object[] {param1,param2});
```

Comment: 2021: queryForObject doesn't work without a rowmapper anymore!