# JdbcTemplate.excute -spring- not working with plsql

Tags: java, spring, oracle, plsql, jdbctemplate

I have a `plsql`-Script. When I run it on `sqldeveloper` it works fine.

But when I run it in `spring boot jdbctemplate`:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(Sql);
```

It doesn't update in db.

#### plsql sample

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE cust_txcutover_uda
        SET TX_CUTOVER_COMMENTS =
            SUBSTR ('aa/bb', 1, INSTR ('aa/bb', '/') - 1)
        WHERE CUST_TXCUTOVER_UDA_ID = '1373';

    COMMIT;
END;
```

I can't find the reason for that, how can I run `plsql` with `jdbctemplate`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JDBC Template for calling Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361538/spring-jdbc-template-for-calling-stored-procedures)

Comment: Is this pl/sql a stored procedure in the data base? if this is the case, you can use SimpleJdbcCall. If not... wouldn't it be easier make it via java?

Comment: Wild guess: The semicolon at the end of your script has to be removed. I don't know much about java, but most time you have to execute a single statement (in this case "BEGIN ... END"). Because of this a semicolon to introduce a second one is not allowed. Beside this: Yevhens answer is corret. You don't need plsql. Just run the update.

Answer (score 2):

As I know jdbcTemplate.execute doesn't support execution of anonymous PL/SQL block. Try execute just

```
UPDATE cust_txcutover_uda
   SET TX_CUTOVER_COMMENTS = SUBSTR ('aa/bb', 1, INSTR ('aa/bb', '/') - 1)
 WHERE CUST_TXCUTOVER_UDA_ID = '1373'
```

without wrap it by begin and end