# Assigning NamedStoredProcedureQuery at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have stored procedures that need to be called to perform the operation. However, for each operation, I have saved the stored procedure name into the database. So, at runtime, based on the operation name I will call the assign stored procedure.

Question: 
1. How can I set the name of the NamedStoredProcedureQuery at runtime?

I am using Spring JPA with Spring boot.

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "sptest",
                procedureName = "usp_helper_test",
                resultClasses = {Config.class},
                parameters = {
                        @StoredProcedureParameter(
                                name = "data",
                                type = String.class,
                                mode = ParameterMode.IN)
                })
})
```

In this above example, I want to set **procedureName** at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore stuff like byte code generation: You can't.
Named stored procedures get their name from the annotations you showed in the question.

Of course you can still use either the `EntityManager` or JDBC (possibly via the `JdbcTemplate`) to call stored procedures by the name they have in the database.

With the `EntityManager` you'd invoke [`EntityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createStoredProcedureQuery-java.lang.String-) in one of it's variants.

For the `JdbcTemplate` approach you can consult [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9361835/66686).

The code you need to write would go in a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations).