# Call Stored Procedure in the Step configuration of Spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to build a job in spring batch to perform below actions :

- Read CSV file
- Dump CSV files into a table
- Call Stored Procedure to perform some action

I am able to write logic for the first 2 points but not sure how to call a Stored procedure?
Also, this procedure should be called after first 2 points are completed, so thinking this should be in another step.

Based on my assumption, I should have a job configuration like this :

```
@Bean
    public Job job(){
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                .start(step1())  --> To read and write CSV file
                .next(step2())   --> To call SP
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .build();
    }
```

Below is my step configuration :

In this step, I am reading 1000 Provider objects at a time from csv and dumping it into a table. This is working as expected.

```
@Bean
    public Step step1(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Provider, Provider>chunk(1000)
                .reader(batchItemReader.providerMultiResourceItemReader())
                .writer(batchItemWriter.providerJdbcBatchItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

To call Stored procedure : SP_UpdateTemp, I am thinking to include step2() but now sure how to do it ?
In this SP, I am reading records from first table and performing some updates on another table.

```
@Bean
    public Step step2(){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                //call procedure

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your step2 could be a simple tasklet step that calls the stored procedure with a `JdbcTemplate` for example:

```
@Bean
public Step step2() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
            .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                // call stored procedure
                jdbcTemplate.update("call SOME_PROC (?, ?)", param1, param2);
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            })
            .build();
}
```

Refer to [Spring JDBC Template for calling Stored Procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361538/spring-jdbc-template-for-calling-stored-procedures) for more details about calling stored procedures with a `JdbcTemplate`.